# jquery/javascript code to obtain full text content of main web page(including links texts but excluding images) of a web page

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to obtain the entire text content of a web page, when the page is open within main window of browser. Is there some way to do this- preferably using jquery, but pure js is also ok for me.
I want to obtain both the normal text as well as link texts also- only images should be excluded

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you mean

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var bodyText = $("body").text();
});
```

http://api.jquery.com/text/

Answer (score 0):

I hope this code help you

```
$(function(){
    var t = $('body > *').not('img').text()
});
```

Comment: Selects a `<body>` element, which is not an `<img>` element. Hmm.

Comment: Oops! Of course should be var t = $('body > *').not('img').text()